# Is the random cluster model ergodic/mixing?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics

Consider the random-cluster model $\mathbb{P}_G^i$ on a finite graph $G$ with parameters $p\in [0,1]$ and $q \in \mathbb{N}_+$ and boundary condition $i=0,1$ (free and wired). The main 2 references that I know of on this topic are  H. Duminil-Copin's [Lectures on the Ising and Potts models on the hypercubic lattice](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00520) and Grimmett's [The Random Cluster Model](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-32891-9).

The former provides a proof (Lemma 1.11) that the infinite limit $\mathbb{P}^1_\infty$ is mixing using the FKG inequality so that
$$
\mathbb{P}^1_\infty [A\cap \tau_x B] \ge \mathbb{P}^1_\infty [A] \mathbb{P}^1_\infty [B]
$$
And the converse in the limit $|x| \to \infty$ using the fact that $\mathbb{P}^\xi \le \mathbb{P}^1$ for any boundary condition $\xi$.

Now if we were to consider the free boundary condition $\mathbb{P}^0_\infty$, the FKG inequality still applies, but the converse is less clear. Indeed, I also looked at the proof in Grimmett (Theorem 4.19). However, I think the proof may be mistaken since the FKG inequality only applies for increasing events $A,B$, whereas the proof took the complement of an increasing event and still applied the same inequality.

Any help on clearing this up would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event $B$ in Grimmett's (4.25) does not have to be increasing. Indeed, in the derivation of (4.25), one only needs $A$ to be increasing:
$$
\phi^0_\Delta(A\cap B) = \phi^0_\Delta(\phi^0_\Delta(1_A1_B \,|\, \mathcal{F}_{\Delta\setminus\Lambda})) = \phi^0_\Delta(\phi^0_\Delta(1_A\,|\, \mathcal{F}_{\Delta\setminus\Lambda})1_B),
$$
since $B\in\mathcal{F}_{\Delta\setminus\Lambda}$.
Now, by FKG (here we use only that $A$ is increasing),
$$
\phi^0_\Delta(1_A\,|\, \mathcal{F}_{\Delta\setminus\Lambda})(\omega) = \phi_\Lambda^\omega(A) \geq \phi^0_\Lambda(A),
$$
by monotonicity in the boundary condition. This gives you
$$
\phi^0_\Delta(A\cap B) \geq \phi^0_\Lambda(A) \phi^0_\Delta(B).
$$
(4.25) follows by first letting $\Delta\uparrow\mathbb{Z}^d$, then observing that the inequality now extends to any $B\in\mathcal{T}$, then finally letting $\Lambda\uparrow\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks!